# Looking for an effective way to allow people to put on a slide show of documents and videos

Tags: gui-design, design, html, css, javascript

Currently we have this

http://torontotigroup.byethost7.com/documents.html

I'm looking for something that is easy to use, for both me and the reader, and works effectively on as many devices as possible.

Currently the page is not truly responsive as the documents can not really be seen effectively on a phone.

Please advise, maybe there is already an effective template out there?

Thinking about using Google Slides.

How can you make google slides appear in a responsive modal form?